# How can I combine two RNN models

Tags: tensorflow

I have a question with tensorflow, now I'm using tensorflow built two RNN models.

- RNN1(encoder) is 3 layers LSTM units with cell size 256
- RNN2(decoder) is 3 layers LSTM units with cell size 512.

Now I want combine two RNNs by the state, which means the last state
   of RNN1 is the first state of RNN2. I want to ask how to implement
   that?

I have tried set RNN1 and RNN2 with the same cell size(512) and use this code:

```
decoder_initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32).clone(cell_state=encoder_state)`    #this code is from Internet.
```

but I think it is not right.

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take two more minutes to make your question more readable, make the problem reproducible and distinct between actual and expected behaviour/output.

Comment: 1) please link us to wherever you got the code from, 2) why do YOU think it's not right? 3) this sounds like a [sequence-to-sequence model](https://github.com/google/seq2seq)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1) the code is from github, https://github.com/thomasschmied/Speech_Recognition_with_Tensorflow. 2) I think it is not right, because RNN1 encoder and RNN2 decoder suppose to be connected by state, but in this code it is just initial all the RNN2 states by RNN1 states. 3) this is seq2seq model, but I'm new in tensorflow, so I don't know how can I implement that. The model which I want to implement is based on this paper. Figure1 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05358.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example code you posted, I'm pretty sure it's correct.

> 2) I think it is not right, because RNN1 encoder and RNN2 decoder suppose to be connected by state, but in this code it is just initial all the RNN2 states by RNN1 states

Although it is initialized to that, if you look in the `build_decoder` function, you see that the `decoder_initial_state` is used in the decoder. So, `encoder_state` -> `decoder_initial_state` -> `build_decoder`

**High Level**

When Tensorflow builds the computation graph, it automatically feeds the result of `RNN1` into `RNN2` because of the way your computation graph was created. When you define operations in Tensorflow, you're not feeding data "directly", you're saying "link these operations together"

**Moving Forward**

A simpler example that you should start with is [Seq2Seq Tutorial](https://github.com/ematvey/tensorflow-seq2seq-tutorials/blob/master/1-seq2seq.ipynb) which walks you through a simple encoder-decoder. This should give you a better understanding so you can tackle the code you posted :)

All the best! Hope this helps